# ASP.Net Custom Delete Function

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a database, I think when I initially generated it, I didn't bother to select the "Generate Delete function" option and now I find myself wanting to add that in.

Currently, I have a gridview bound to the database with a delete button for each row. It seems like I should be able to just run a custom delete function with the following code;

```
protected void gvUsers_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(database.ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM userlist WHERE Username='@insUsername'";
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("insUsername", gvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text));

        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I had no issues when using the above code as an insert function...I think it has something to do with the fact that the button is part of the GridView? At the moment I get; Deleting is not supported by data source 'database' unless DeleteCommand is specified.

Any help on this would be great, thanks.

Comment: can you clarify more what is your problem definitely? I can't understand the problem and what does you need to do!

Comment: Why is this error "Deleting is not supported by data source 'database' unless DeleteCommand is specified." appearing? How can I fix it up? I didn't have this issue with an insert command...

Comment: @FizzBuzz: I'd have to see some of your other code to be sure but I suspect its because you are using a delete button which the code knows needs the delete command to be specified (else how does it know what that button does?). Since you are not specifying it it throws that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put SQL into the DeleteCommand and not just a procedure name...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deletecommand.aspx shows how this is done but the key line is:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Order Details] WHERE OrderID=@OrderID;DELETE FROM Orders WHERE OrderID=@OrderID;"
```

This should get around the problem of it not allowing delete without a deletecommand. :)

**Edit to add:**

One other alternative that I found suggested that that error is thrown after that function is run when it comes to pass the delete on. You can use `e.Cancel=true` to cancel the delete event after you have done the delete yourself. [Source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1762690.aspx/1)

Comment: Oh wow yeah, OK. I was actively avoiding that because I didn't think it was appropriate. I suppose that given the delete command comes from the GridView, that does actually make sense...Tried it and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm a big fan of the `e.cancel` event myself but it does the job. It probably has potentially negative side effects like not firing the RowDeleted event and I don't know if the fact that the control doesn't think it has deleted anything whereas the underlying data has actually been deleted, etc. will cause problems. End of the day though if it works and it is the best solution for your code then go for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Not a full answer*

Your query text should be:

`"DELETE FROM userlist WHERE Username=@insUsername"`

Since you're using parameters you don't need single quotes.

Comment: Yeah...just something I tried to try and figure out why it won't work...duly noted though, I'll get rid of the quotes.